# Custom query not working in plugin admin page

Tags: plugin-development, get-posts

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but I cannot use `get_post`, `get_posts` or `WP_Query` in my plugin admin page. I can use `get_user_meta`, and `get_userdata`, so I'm a bit confused as to why I cannot use `get_post`, `get_posts` etc.

What could be causing this? And how can I fix it?

EDIT -------------------------------------------------------

Sorry about that, thought it was simple include/require solution. Here's my code:

```
        <?php 
        //require the WP header file so we can use the WP_Query class
        //require ABSPATH.'/wp-blog-header.php'; --> This didn't work for me

        //my method for returning values from my plugin DB table
        $requests = ds_get_user_control_requests(); 


        if( $requests ):


        foreach( $requests as $r ):

            $user = get_userdata($r->user_id);

            $p = get_post($r->post_id);

            ?>


            <tr class="hentry alternate" valign="top">

                <td class="approve-it">

                    <p><a href="<?php print get_admin_url().'admin.php?page=ds_approve_user_control_request&post_id='.$r->post_id.'&user_id='.$r->user_id; ?>">Update This Request</a></p>

                </td>


                <td class="status">

                    <p><strong>Request Status</strong>: <?php print ucfirst($r->status); ?></p>

                </td>


                <td class="user">

                    <p><strong>User ID</strong>: <?php print $r->user_id; ?></p>

                    <p><strong>User's Name</strong>: <?php print $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name; ?></p>

                    <p><strong>User's Email</strong>: <?php print '<a href="mailto:'.$user->user_email.'">'.$user->user_email.'</a>'; ?></p>

                </td>


                <td class="user-biz">

                    <p><strong>Business Name</strong>: <?php print get_user_meta($user->ID,'biz_name',true); ?></p>

                    <p><strong>Business URL</strong>: <?php print '<a href="'.get_user_meta($user->ID,'biz_url',true).'" target=_blank">'.get_user_meta($user->ID,'biz_url',true).'</a>'; ?></p>

                    <p><strong>Business Email</strong>: 

                    <?php 

                        if( get_user_meta($user->ID,'biz_email',true) )
                            print '<a href="mailto:'.get_user_meta($user->ID,'biz_email',true).'">'.get_user_meta($user->ID,'biz_email',true).'</a>';
                        else
                            print 'N/A';

                    ?>  

                    </p>

                </td>


                <td class="post">                                           

                    <p><strong>Post ID</strong>: <?php print $r->post_id; ?></p>

                    <p><strong>Post Name</strong>: <?php print $p['post_title']; ?></p>

                </td>


            </tr>

       <?php           

       endforeach; 


       endif;

       ?>
```

I thought that since I can use get_user_meta on the admin pages that get_post/WP_Query would also be available, a poor assumption on my part.

Thanks again

Comment: You can, but you haven't shown us your code, so we can't help.

Comment: Please file an [edit] and add all code and info relevant to your question.

Comment: Which posts would you expect to be available in custom admin page?

Comment: Did you try global $post; $post->id?

Comment: @Shawn no I didn't. Would $post be available since it's my plugin page? Or is it after I call get_post that I set global $post?